# How to add new rows to existing rows in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` developed in Netbeans forms. I want the program to work in such a way that when I click a button, the new prepared records will be added to the existing ones. My problem is when I want to add new records, the moment I click the button, it replaces the existing one. Can anyone help me with the method to add new records to existing ones?

Comment: Hopefully this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24583025/1057230) along with the answers below, will help in your endeavour :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post anymore questions, please carefully/thoroughly read **1.** [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). **2.** [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) **3.** [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Use [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) and simple call [DefaultTableModel#addRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29) method on it to add a new row.

- Here table having 4 existing rows
- A new row is added on button click

sample code:

```
    Object data[][] = { { "111 Hello", "Capital1", "TX 11111" },
                        { "222 Hello", "Capital2", "TX 22222" },
                        { "333 Hello", "Capital3", "TX 33333" },
                        { "444 Hello", "Capital4", "TX 44444" } 
                      };
    String col[] = { "Name", "Capital", "TX" };

    final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
    final JTable table = new JTable(model);

    ....

    final JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Object[] newRecord = { "555 Hello", "Capital5", "TX 55555" };
            model.addRow(newRecord); // <== Adding new row here
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have followed your method but still when I click on the Jbutton, the it replaces the records in the first row without adding it as new records. I am using netbeans forms please help me

Comment: have you tried with sample code that I shared you. Please first try it if this doesn't work then share your code in your original post.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is when I want to add new records, the moment i click the button, it replaces the existing one.

Don't create a new TableModel.

Instead you should be using the `DefaultTableModel.addRow(...)` method to add a new row to the end of the table.